# How can i call my own function like "getValue()" in typehead jquery plugin when press enter or mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, typeahead

I am using

> Bootstrap Typeahead JS plugin

for auto-complete search, i want to call my own function "getValue()" after search when press enter or mouse click.
one function enter is working but mouse click is not working.
[I am using that plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.js)

**here is my keyboard Enter code**

```js
keyup: function (e) {
      switch(e.keyCode) {


        case 9: // tab
        case 13: // enter
          if (!this.shown) return;
          this.select();
    this.getValue()// i have define this it is working
          break;


      }

      e.preventDefault();
   },
```

```html
<input class="typeahead form-control"  id="typehead" name="customer_name"  type="text">
```

```js
 click: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.select();
     this.getValue();// i have define this but it do not work show me error
      this.$element.focus();
      this.hide();
   
    },
```

**my call function**

```js
function getValue(){
   // code here
  }
```

i do not understand where i use mouse click function call , i have call several place but it do not work, show error.

Comment: Any Errors in the console?

Comment: when i add my function "getValue()" in click function then show Errors.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: TypeError: this.getValue is not a function "in click function section error show"